# How to decompress the parameter tuple in map function invocation?

Tags: python

suppose we have a function sum takes two num and return its sum:

```
def sum(a, b):
    return a + b
```

and we want to use map to calculate the sum on some iterable container:

```
map(sum, [(1, 2), (3, 4)])
```

it will raise an exception:

```
TypeError: sum() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

What happens here is that sum get invoked on parameter (1, 2) and (3, 4), that gives us an error. We can do that:

sum(*(1, 2)) would correctly return. here is my problem:
how could we use the map to pass this tuple into sum gracefully?
here is a solution, but not quite as gracefully as what I want:

```
map(lambda x: sum(*x), [(1, 2), (3, 4)])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is exactly what [`starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) is for:

```
from itertools import starmap

starmap(sum, [(1, 2), (3, 4)])
```